# Partially specialize with respect to values in struct given as template parameter

Tags: c++

I have a struct which I use as template parameter to configure some classes:

```
template <int _DIM, class _TYPE>
struct CONFIG{
    static constexpr int DIM = _DIM;
    using TYPE = _TYPE;
};
```

I then need to partially specialize a class. I currently do this the following way:

Lines that will instantiate the template:

```
template <class CONFIG> instantiate(){
    Calculator<CONFIG::DIM, typename CONFIG::NODE> calc;
}
```

The template to specialize:

```
template <class TYPE>
struct Calculator<2, TYPE>{
    static void fct(TYPE t){

    }
};
```

Would there be a way to directly instantiate and specialize Calculator with template parameter of type CONFIG?

Comment: Do not use reserved names.

Comment: By that, T.C. means names beginning with an underscore are reserved and shouldn't be used by your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your instantiation like so:

```
template <class Config> instantiate(){
    Calculator<Config> calc;
}
```

Then specialize like this:

```
template <class T>
struct Calculator<CONFIG<2, T>>{
    static void fct(T t){

    }
};
```

It's generally a bad idea to overload names like you did for the template parameter `CONFIG` and the struct `CONFIG`. Although they are related to you, the compiler treats them very differently.